# install tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need help installing the "tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg" package or any of the stacks such as hector_slam, hector_mapping, etc within the package. I keep getting error: No Valid Packages or stacks listed as arguments. I used: rosdep install tu-darmsstadt-ros-pkg.

I would really appreciate for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30313/install-tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg-package?/) by [genzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2037/genzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [genzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2037/genzo/) on 2012-03-26**:
Im sorry for the late response. but thanks a lot! It worked. I was be able to install the hector_mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is because we didn't do the necessary steps yet which are necessary to let our stacks get build and published as .debs via Willow Garage's build system. I'll have to check how that works, but with a major robotics competition coming up next week it'll probably be 2 weeks till I get to do it. You can always manually check out and build everything e.g. using

```
svn checkout http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg-read-only
```

Note that the path of this checked out working copy has to be inside the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH as described [here](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH).

After performing the above steps, you should the be able to build packages using for example

```
rosmake hector_mapping
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1